# Delete header from some pages in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to delete header from different (not even and/or odd pages, just random) pages in Word 2007. How could I do this ?

I want for my project to delete headers from each chapter but if I delete manually, all headers will be deleted.
I checked for each chapter Different first page option, but it doesn't work for some chapters. :|

Please help

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have a section break at the end of each chapter. It may not be working on some chapters because there is no section break.

Then the **Different First Page** option should work. If you need more flexibility for a particular chapter, you can uncheck **Link to Previous** for that chapter and the headers in that chapter will not affect or be affected by previous chapters.

[image: Link to Previous]

Comment: Where is placed "Link to Previous" option ? I didn't see it

Comment: @Teodorescu I added an image (I'm on Word 2010, but I think it is in the same place in 2007). The **Header & Footer Tools** tab only shows when you are editing a header or footer.